# NoScript vs Ghostery & DoNotTrackMe, add-ons functionality

Tags: firefox, browser-addons

I've been trying to figure out what is the main difference is between some Firefox addons: NoScript, Ghostery, DoNotTrackMe. I am not a very tech-geek guy.

The main question is: 
Once you install NoScript, is it redundant to install Ghostery or DoNotTrackMe (those two seem to have the same function with different databases)? Do they perform the same tasks?

Answer (score 2):

this is a topic that comes up every now and then and has been answered on Ghostery support board.  Here are some relevant links for you:

- [difference between Ghostery and NoScript](https://web.archive.org/web/20150418121539/https://getsatisfaction.com/ghostery/topics/are_noscript_and_ghostery_the_same_thing)
- [complimeting Ghostery with other adddons](https://web.archive.org/web/20150422165049/https://getsatisfaction.com/ghostery/topics/privacy_security_add_ons_that_best_compliment_ghostery_seeking_ghosterys_thoughts)

Now to address your actual question:
It is not redundant to have an additional addon with NoScript installed.  The main reason for this is that NoScript does not prevent third party tracking thats non-script based, while Ghostery and DNTMe will. There are a bunch of ways this tracking is accomplished, but for the purposes of simplicity, most common way is image pixels and NoScript ignores them.

Comment: Thank you for answering. A little follow up:

if NoScript blocks all scripts including those that leaves cookies behind therefore the cookies never get a chance to be set and setting Firefox to not accept third-party cookies help eliminating them as well (I assume). So then the function of DNTM & Ghostery is preventing tracking that takes place using a different methods... do you know what are those?

Comment: Technically, not all cookies are created from scripts they may also be written out by HTTP requests directly. Not accepting third party cookies will definitely help reduce the number of total cookies, but eliminate them all it shall not. There are advantages to denying all 3rd party cookies of course, but this is why we've created Ghostery in the first place: the control should be in users hands site-by-site, not a global off.

Comment: As far as tracking methods that NoScript would miss. Its basically anything that makes an HTTP request but is not an item NoScript looks for: images, css, pure links, and other web elements.  Of course the methods of tracking with just this stuff is less effective, but its there nonetheless.